# Bad CSRF token with AngularJS and Express

Tags: angularjs, cookies, express, csrf, passport.js

I would like to add a CSRF protection in my app which uses a MEAN stack.

I tried the answer already given by someone : [CSRF Protection in ExpressJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19566949/csrf-protection-in-expressjs/22984309#22984309)

But it was for the older express version, so I made some changes :

```
app.use(cookieParser(config.cookieSecret, { httpOnly: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(session({ secret: config.sessionSecret, resave: false, saveUninitialized: true }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());
app.use(csrf({value: function(req) {
        var token = (req.body && req.body._csrf)
            || (req.query && req.query._csrf)
            || (req.headers['x-csrf-token'])
            || (req.headers['x-xsrf-token']);
        return token;
    }
}));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.csrfToken());
  next();
});
```

I can see the token named `XSRF-TOKEN` is well generated on my app (using Chrome inspection).

But when I post a form (Angular frontend), I have an error about the token :

`{"message":"invalid csrf token","error":{"expose":true,"code":"EBADCSRFTOKEN","statusCode":403,"status":403}}`

Did I miss something ? I'm wondering if `req.csrfToken()` generates the good token given by Angular...

**EDIT :**

I just see the `XSRF-TOKEN` is used by AngularJS in `$http` requests **only**. So I think I have to add a hidden input in my form to post with csrf value, to be checked by Express, but how ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally I was able to send the good token value. Here's the complete answer.

[AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) uses CSRF protection (called XSRF by Angular) during requests made with `$http` service.

> When performing **XHR** requests, the **$http** service reads a token from a
>   cookie (by default, **XSRF-TOKEN**) and sets it as an HTTP header
>   (**X-XSRF-TOKEN**). Since only JavaScript that runs on your domain could
>   read the cookie, your server can be assured that the XHR came from
>   JavaScript running on your domain. The header will not be set for
>   cross-domain requests.

There are many posts which explained how to send XSRF-TOKEN with **ExpressJS 3.xx**, but some things change with **4.xx version**. [Connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) middlewares are not included anymore. [Express](http://expressjs.com/) uses its own middelware : [cookie-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser), [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser), [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session), and [csurf](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf).

### **1 - Send XSRF-TOKEN cookie**

The first step is to send the cookie, from the backend to the frontend (Express to Angular) :

```
var express         = require('express');
var app             = express();
var cookieParser    = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser      = require('body-parser');
var session         = require('express-session');
var config          = require('./lib/config'); //config.js file with hard-coded options.
var csrf            = require('csurf');

app.use(cookieParser(config.cookieSecret, { httpOnly: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(session({ 
    name: 'sessionID', 
    secret: config.sessionSecret, 
    cookie: {
        path: '/',
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: false,
        maxAge: 3600000
    },
    rolling: true, 
    resave: false, 
    saveUninitialized: true 
}));
app.use(csrf());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.csrfToken());
    next();
});
```

Now Angular is able to set its HTTP header (X-XSRF-TOKEN) during **$http** requests. Example :

```
<body ng-app="testApp">
    <div ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
        <form role="form" ng-submit="login()" >
           <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" />
           <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" />
           <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
        </form>
        <p style="color:red">{{loginMsg}}</p>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('testApp', ['ngResource']);
    app.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.user = {};
        $scope.loginMsg = '';
        $scope.login = function () {
             $http.post('/login', $scope.user).success(function () {
                  $window.location.href='/profile';
             }).error(function () {
                  $scope.loginMsg = 'Wrong credentials, try again.';
             });
        };
    });
</script>
```

### **2 - Add a _csrf input in non-Angular forms**

That was my issue, I didn't know how to add this input. Finally I created a new Angular service named `$csrf` :

```
    app.factory('$csrf', function () {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split('; ');
        for (var i=0; i<cookies.length; i++) {
          var cookie = cookies[i].split('=');
          if(cookie[0].indexOf('XSRF-TOKEN') > -1) {
            return cookie[1];
          }
        }
        return 'none';
    });
```

I made an example on Plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/G8oD0dDJQmjWaa6D0x3u

Hope my answer will help.

Comment: Is this solution also valid if your frontend and backend domain is different? For an instance my backend server is running on port 4200 and frontend is on 3000

Comment: Yes, you can see this answer to may have a better idea : http://stackoverflow.com/a/33175322/2904349

Comment: Does that mean I will have to implement may be an interceptor to pass on the cookie value manually everytime to angular JS headers?

Comment: As said in the AngularJS documentation, it will check automatically if the cookie exists and set it as HTTP header during XHR request (using $http, no need interceptor). If you need to make requests without using $http, you can pass $csrf everytime in the header, or make an interceptor.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer really helped. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

if anyone gets "csurf configuration error", try this:

```
app.use( csrf( { cookie: true } ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created repository that you can directly use.

## node

[https://github.com/nil4you/node-csrf-and-http-only-cookie-with-spa](https://github.com/nil4you/angular-csrf-and-httponly-cookie-demo)

## angular

https://github.com/nil4you/angular-csrf-and-httponly-cookie-demo

ask any question here any comment, as I can't see much coding issue, it's all about right setup issue.